# Can't see changes in K8s after I apply yaml with the new API version

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am upgrading K8s from 1.15 to 1.16. Before I do it, I must migrate my daemonsets, deployment, statefulset etc. to the apps/v1 version. But when I do it, I don't understand the K8s behaviour.

Let's say, that we have a daemonset:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: spot-interrupt-handler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spot-interrupt-handler
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spot-interrupt-handler
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: spot-interrupt-handler
      containers:
      - name: spot-interrupt-handler
        image: madhuriperi/samplek8spotinterrupt:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: SPOT_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
      nodeSelector:
        lifecycle: Ec2Spot
```

I change the first line to **apps/v1** and successfully apply this yaml to K8s. Nothing changes after it, the pods are not restarted.
I get this notification:

```
daemonset.apps/spot-interrupt-handler configured
```

1. Is it a normal behavior? Shouldn't it be restarted after I change the API version?

Then I want to see, that this API version change is really applied to K8s etcd.

```
kubectl get ds spot-interrupt-handler -n default -o yaml
```

And that is what I see at the start of the yaml definition:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"DaemonSet","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"spot-interrupt-handler","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"spot-interrupt-handler"}},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"spot-interrupt-handler"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"POD_NAME","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.name"}}},{"name":"NAMESPACE","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"}}},{"name":"SPOT_POD_IP","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"status.podIP"}}}],"image":"madhuriperi/samplek8spotinterrupt:latest","imagePullPolicy":"Always","name":"spot-interrupt-handler"}],"nodeSelector":{"lifecycle":"Ec2Spot"},"serviceAccountName":"spot-interrupt-handler"}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-02-09T08:34:33Z"
```

2. Why is **extensions/v1beta1** on the top? I expect it to be **apps/v1**.
3. I see, that the new version of API is in the last-applied-configuration. Does it mean, that this DaemonSet will work after the upgrade to 1.16?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your setup in GKE environment and after upgrading kubernetes version from 1.15 to 1.16 daemonset's `apiVersion` has changed to `apiVersion: apps/v1`.

I've started with GKE version `1.15.12` and applied your configuration. Once successfully applied I've changed apiVersion to `apps/v1`,  `extensions/v1beta1` has remained as the current `apiVersion`.

After upgrading kubernetes version to
`version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.15-gke.6000"` the DS in now  `apps/v1`.

To check if the same behavior will happen again I've created a DS and upgraded kubernetes version without changing apiVersion and it has changed by itself to `apps/v1`.